# Helm: Incompatible versions between client and server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After I have run `helm list` I got following error:

> Error: incompatible versions client[v2.9.0] server[v2.8.2]

I did a helm init to install the compatible tiller version 
"Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.
(Use --client-only to suppress this message, or --upgrade to upgrade Tiller to the current version.)".

Any pointers?

Comment: In Error : client represents helm CLI version and server represents tiller version, and you are using two different versions. 
I'll suggest you to use helm3 from which tiller is removed and handled it in helm CLI.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To upgrade your tiller version to the same version of the client, just run `helm init --upgrade`

NOTE: If you're trying to downgrade the server version to match your local client version, run the following instead:

`helm init --upgrade --force-upgrade`

Comment: How to downgrade client helm version ?

Comment: people are just automatically updating their server versions when they use the client? seems highly irresponsible

Comment: This really should not be considered the correct answer. There are two good solutions below.

Comment: Upgrading the production software simply to satisfy the client software is unwise.

Comment: All you need is to just downgrade the helm client as mentioned in the second answer so that you don't mess anything.

Comment: Although it may be dangerous to upgrade the server version "willy nilly" as they say, I was able to successfully upgrade from 2.16.0 to 2.17.0 easily without any issues

Answer (score 86):

Like the OP, I had this error:

```
$ helm list
Error: incompatible versions client[v2.10.0] server[v2.9.1]
```

Updating the server wasn't an option for me so I needed to brew install a previous version of the client. I hadn't previously installed client[v2.9.1] (or any previous client version) and thus couldn't just `brew switch kubernetes-helm 2.9.1`. I ended up having to follow the steps in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757092/2356383

Which basically says

- Look on Github for the correct kubernetes-helm.rb file for the version you want (2.9.1 in my case): https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=kubernetes-helm&type=Commits
- Click the commit hash (78d6425 in my case)
- Click the "View" button to see the whole file
- Click the "Raw" button
- And copy the url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/78d64252f30a12b6f4b3ce29686ab5e262eea812/Formula/kubernetes-helm.rb

Now that I had the url for the correct kubernetes-helm.rb file, I ran the following:

```
$ brew unlink kubernetes-helm
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/78d64252f30a12b6f4b3ce29686ab5e262eea812/Formula/kubernetes-helm.rb
$ brew switch kubernetes-helm 2.9.1
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a better answer as it doesn't alter server version but alters your local version accordingly

Comment: Currently I had the problem, that the tab completion was broken after I've changed the helm client version. You have to reload it with `helm completion <SHELL>`. https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_completion.md

Comment: This solution no longer works: "Invalid usage: Installation of kubernetes-helm from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! 'brew extract kubernetes-helm' to stable tap on GitHub instead. (UsageError))". 
The helm installer script below still works, though.

Answer (score 32):

Another alternative, if changing the server version is not an option, is to use the 
[helm installer script](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)

The script lets you chose a specific version like so
`./get_helm.sh -v v2.13.1`

Comment: Nice simple solution, that works and doesn't require changing the server version. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the -v flag solved my issue. 
Agreed, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach to using different versions through Docker.

https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/helm

**Example**: list helm packages installed

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v ~/.kube/config:/root/.kube/config \
    -v ~/.helm:/root/.helm alpine/helm:2.9.1 \
    list
```

This is a long command; but it can be shortened with an alias

```
alias helm_2_9_1="docker run -ti --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/apps -v ~/.kube/config:/root/.kube/config \
    -v ~/.helm:/root/.helm alpine/helm:2.9.1"
```

And then the command is

```
helm_2_9_1 list
```

Comment: The alias should be put in single quotes, so the $(pwd) is evaluated when executing the command and not when the alias is created.

Comment: Best answer if you have to use and old helm release and don't want to install much on your workstation !

Comment: Do you know how to make this work if you are connecting to pods on AWS?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is for who want to choose(downgrade) helm client version, and the brew install is not work.You can just manually install the binary file from [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases).

example:

1. you can unlink the current helm

   ```
   brew unlink kubernetes-helm
   ```
2. choose and download the helm version you want in [github helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases)------[v2.8.2](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.8.2)
3. unzip the file and put the helm unix executable binary file into /usr/local/bin directory

   go to the directory you just downloaded

   ```
   cd /Users/your_name/Downloads
   ```

   unzip the file

   ```
   gunzip -c helm-v2.8.2-darwin-amd64.tar.gz | tar xopf -
   ```

   copy to the bin directory

   ```
   cp darwin-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin
   ```
4. now you will see the right version of helm you want

   ```
   helm version
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For those having installed their helm client with snap, to downgrade/upgrade it to a specific version you can simply:

- Uninstall it: `snap remove helm`
- Check the available versions: `snap info helm`
- Install the one you want: `snap install helm --channel=X.X/stable --classic`

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the most advanced answer... but my team runs kubernetes clusters that already have tiller installed.  While setting up a new laptop, I wanted my helm to match the tiller version, so I found it like this:

```
TILLER_POD=`kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep tiller | awk '{print $1}'`
kubectl exec -n kube-system $TILLER_POD -- /tiller -version
```

Then I just used the normal helm install instructions from that release number (being on Linux, its basically just curl and unzip to /usr/local/bin).

Answer (score 1):

If you are windows user and installed helm through choco, firstly go its folder (mine is C:\ProgramData\chocolatey) and delete helm.exe from bin folder.

Then, corresponding heml.exe file should be downloaded. By using the above comments, decide the location where you will download exe from. For instance, I used that path: https://get.helm.sh/helm-v2.14.3-windows-amd64.tar.gz

Finally extract the helm.exe from tar and move into choco bin folder. Of course, you can directly add this exe into the path.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue, but in my case I wanna only to upgrade Tiller to specific version (because helm client is running remotely).

So, error was:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: incompatible versions client[v2.11.0] server[v2.9.1]
```

Accordingly to documentation I've run:

```
$ kubectl --namespace=kube-system set image deployments/tiller-deploy tiller=gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.11.0

deployment.extensions/tiller-deploy image updated
```

Documentation reference:

https://helm.sh/docs/install/#upgrading-tiller