# Helm list does not show anything when I have a kubectl context of my cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I just setup helm on my home PC and wanted to use it right away. However `helm list` / `helm ls` does not show anything even tho I configured `kubectl` properly. `kubectl` is able to fetch any information. `Tiller` is already installed since we use `helm` at work all the time.

This is what I tried to far:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl config current-context
gke_mycompany-cluster_europe-west3_mycompany-cluster
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> helm ls
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED STATUS  CHART   APP VERSION
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

As you can see the context is available but `helm ls` is not returning anything.

Comment: Your file `~/.kube/config` is configured correctly? The helm version you are using in both places are the same?

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR**  You may want to try listing releases in all namespaces `helm list --all-namespaces`

There is not enough information to draw definite conclusion, but helm 3 introduced some changes in how helm find releases that may affect you. And since your install is recent I suspect you have helm 3 client, furthermore chances are high your work cluster is still on helm 2.

In helm 3 information about releases is stored in the the same namespace as the chart (this used to be stored by tiller in kube-system or in each namespace when using RBAC) therefore you can only see releases that are installed in the current namespace.

> helm list command no longer lists all releases by default. Instead, it
> will list only the releases in the namespace of your current
> kubernetes context.

You may want to try listing releases in all namespaces `helm list --all-namespaces`

For more information see official [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#release-names-are-now-scoped-to-the-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

You may have deployed your releases with helm 2 and then updated your client to helm 3.

This would result in no releases showing.

To fix, either install helm 2 again (e.g. [Helm: Incompatible versions between client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50701224/1514728)) or complete the upgrade to helm 3.